# How to export to excel with pandas dataframe with multi column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm stuck at exporting a multi index dataframe to excel, in the matter what I'm looking for.

This is what I'm looking for in excel.
I know I have to add an extra Index Parameter on the left for the row of `SRR (%)` and `Traction (-)`, but how?

[image]

My code so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Step 1': {'Step Typ': 'Traction', 'SRR (%)': {1: 8.384, 2: 9.815, 3: 7.531, 4: 10.209, 5: 7.989, 6: 7.331, 7: 5.008, 8: 2.716, 9: 9.6, 10: 7.911}, 'Traction (-)': {1: 5.602, 2: 6.04, 3: 2.631, 4: 2.952, 5: 8.162, 6: 9.312, 7: 4.994, 8: 2.959, 9: 10.075, 10: 5.498}, 'Temperature': 30, 'Load': 40}, 'Step 3': {'Step Typ': 'Traction', 'SRR (%)': {1: 2.909, 2: 5.552, 3: 5.656, 4: 9.043, 5: 3.424, 6: 7.382, 7: 3.916, 8: 2.665, 9: 4.832, 10: 3.993}, 'Traction (-)': {1: 9.158, 2: 6.721, 3: 7.787, 4: 7.491, 5: 8.267, 6: 2.985, 7: 5.882, 8: 3.591, 9: 6.334, 10: 10.43}, 'Temperature': 80, 'Load': 40}, 'Step 5': {'Step Typ': 'Traction', 'SRR (%)': {1: 4.765, 2: 9.293, 3: 7.608, 4: 7.371, 5: 4.87, 6: 4.832, 7: 6.244, 8: 6.488, 9: 5.04, 10: 2.962}, 'Traction (-)': {1: 6.656, 2: 7.872, 3: 8.799, 4: 7.9, 5: 4.22, 6: 6.288, 7: 7.439, 8: 7.77, 9: 5.977, 10: 9.395}, 'Temperature': 30, 'Load': 70}, 'Step 7': {'Step Typ': 'Traction', 'SRR (%)': {1: 9.46, 2: 2.83, 3: 3.249, 4: 9.273, 5: 8.792, 6: 9.673, 7: 6.784, 8: 3.838, 9: 8.779, 10: 4.82}, 'Traction (-)': {1: 5.245, 2: 8.491, 3: 10.088, 4: 9.988, 5: 4.886, 6: 4.168, 7: 8.628, 8: 5.038, 9: 7.712, 10: 3.961}, 'Temperature': 80, 'Load': 70} }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
items = list()
series = list()

for item, d in data.items():
    items.append(item)
    series.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d))
df = pd.concat(series, keys=items)
df.set_index(['Step Typ', 'Load', 'Temperature'], inplace=True).T.to_excel('testfile.xlsx')
```

The picture below, shows `df.set_index(['Step Typ', 'Load', 'Temperature'], inplace=True).T` as a dataframe: (somehow close, but not exactly what I'm looking for):

[image]

### Edit 1:

Found a good solution, not the exact one I was looking for, but it's still worth using it.

```
df.reset_index().drop(["level_0","level_1"], axis=1).pivot(columns=["Step Typ", "Load", "Temperature"], values=["SRR (%)", "Traction (-)"]).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).to_excel("solution.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: 'in the matter what I'm looking for.' Can you show a table example you want to get?

Comment: The first image is the example I'm looking for. The code below, is the closest I can get to it. How do I modify the dataframe, so I can `df.to_excel('path')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a good solution, not the exact one I was looking for, but it's still worth using it.

```
df.reset_index().drop(["level_0","level_1"], axis=1).pivot(columns=["Step Typ", "Load", "Temperature"], values=["SRR (%)", "Traction (-)"]).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).to_excel("solution.xlsx")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain clearely and show the output you are looking for?

To export a table to excel use `df.to_excel('path', index=True/False)`

where:
`index=True or False` - to insert or not the index column into the file